# How Import Brazilian Portuguese in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, localization, xliff

I'm having trouble import xliff files of languages of  specific regions.  The current example is pt-BR.xliff.  Xcode keeps classifying it as just pt.  How do name the file so that xcode can easily import the xliff file for localization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the xliff file for the defined language and replace it with the language plus region code everywhere.

Example: "pt" -> "pt-BR" to get Brazilian Portuguese.

Comment: Would you mind marking your answer as accepted to make it appear that a solution has been found out, please?  